# Angular wait for subscribe to finish before return data

Tags: angular, observable

Hi have a very simple function that call an endpoint to retrieve my user, I use it in my header to show the connected user but don't want to call the endpoint every time the header is rendered.

So I'm trying something like this:

```
public getUser(): User {
    if (!this.user) {
     
      this.http.get<User>(environment.apiRoot + '/me').subscribe(res => {
        this.setUser(res);
        return this.user.value;
      }, err => {

      });
    } else {
      return this.user.value;
    }
  }
```

With the `setUser` function:

```
public setUser(u: User): void {
    if (!this.user) {
      this.user = new BehaviorSubject(u);
    } else {
      this.user.next(u);
    }
  }
```

And the `BehaviorSubject`:  `private user: BehaviorSubject<User>;`

In my header component I call it like this in the `ngOnInit`:

```
this.user = this.appState.getUser();
console.log(this.user);
```

But the user in the console.log is always undefined, why it doesn't wait for the subscription in the `getUser` function ?

Comment: You should return the observable and subscribe to it where you need it, returning from within the `subscribe` won't return from the `getUser()` function

Answer (score 9):

You have an asynchronous function that you're calling with mixed reactive and imperative programming. When it comes to asynchronous functions, you should stay with the reactive approach and not try to determine when a certain code has finished, but instead just wait for it to finish and then invoke the callback or the responsible handler subsequently.

In your code the `getUser()` function is an `async` function, since you have the inner `http.get()` call. The `http.get()` will return an `Observable`, which you `subscribe` to inside your function unnecessarily. What you should do instead is return the inner `observable` from the function, and `subscribe` where you actually need it.

We can rewrite your `getUser` function like below (note that there is no need for the imperative `setUser`-function)

```
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(environment.apiRoot + '/me');
}
```

and in your outer scope subscribe to it like

```
this.appState.getUser().subscribe(user => {
    console.log(user)
});
```

To take it further, this makes it easier to work with observables in your templates as well.

Suppose you assign the returned observable to a variable, `user$`, you don't even have to subscribe to it!

Just get the user like

`this.user$ = this.appState.getUser();`

to get your observable, and then in your template use the `async` pipe to let Angular subscribe and unsubscribe automatically.

`<span>Hello, my name is {{user$ | async}}!</span>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `getUser` function to wait for subscription to finish, you will have to return observable. And then use `.subscribe()` with `this.appState.getUser()`.

```
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    if (!this.user) {
      return this.http.get<User>(environment.apiRoot + '/me').pipe(map(res => {
        this.setUser(res);
        return this.user.value;
      }, err => {

      }));
    } else {
      return of(this.user.value);
    }
  }

this.appState.getUser().subscribe(user => {
    console.log(user)
});
```